# Optimizing UIScrollView with subviews

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, subviews

I have problem with UIScrollView, I try create sth like table with own rows ( separate nib ). Everything works good with 1-10 rows, but problem occurs with more than 20 elements. The application starts working slow, and stunt. Is there any solution to optimalize scroll view for 100-200 own subviews?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). That's precisely what it's designed for.

Comment: So it mean there are not any ways to optimize uiscrollview to display that count of views?

Comment: `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` that is specifically optimized for scrolling through many subviews.

Answer (score 1):

UITableView and UICollectionView are both optimizing by removing subviews that are no longer needed and putting them in a reuse queue. By reusing those views the system does not have to create and destroy their backing layers but can reuse them. This way you only have ever as many subviews on screen as can fit.

Typically you want to add/remove visible subviews in either the layoutSubviews of a scroll view subclass or the corresponding didScroll delegate method. Personally I prefer the layoutSubviews since it is a bit earlier in the chain of events.

Basically you would get a reusable subview from your reuse queue as soon as at least 1 px of the subview should appear within the bounds of the scroll view and remove the subview as soon as no pixel of it is visible any more.

If you use UITableview or UICollectionView instead of a plain scroll view they provide a mechanism to register views in NIB for certain reuse identifiers and then the dequeueing will automatically load a new instance of a subview from NIB is none is queue or dequeue one if there is.